# Can I set a better structure to Symfony 2 / doctrine results?

Tags: symfony, cakephp, doctrine-orm

I'm building an API in Symfony and I'm struggling with the default format the QueryBuilder gives me for my json.

In CakePhp when I get data it is put into a nested array, with each model separated out so something like this

```
$this->Person->find( 'first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Person.id' => $personId
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Address' => array(
            'fields' => array( 'Address.town' )
        )
    ),
    'fields' => array( 'Person.id', 'Person.name' )
) );
```

gives me a result like this

```
array(2) [
    'Person' => array(2) [
        'id' => string (3) "596"
        'name' => string (13) "Michael Bates"
    ]
    'Address' => array(1) [
        array(3) [
            'id' => string (3) "125"
            'town' => string (8) "New York"
            'AddressesPerson' => array(4) [
                'id' => string (4) "4270"
                'address_id' => string (3) "125"
                'person_id' => string (3) "596"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

where Person and Address are separated out.

In Symfony/Doctrine I can't work out how to get the same structure in the result. When I have this

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('person')
                     ->select('person.id as person_id, person.name')
                     ->addSelect('address.id as address_id, address.town')
                     ->leftJoin('person.address', 'address')
                     ->where('person.id = :person_id')
                     ->setParameter('person_id', $id);
return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I get the person and address data in the same array like this

```
array(1) {
    ["result"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(4) {
            ["person_id"]=> string(3) "596"
            ["name"]=> string (13) "Michael Bates"
            ["address_id"]=> string(3) "125"
            ["town"]=> string (8) "New York"
        } 
    }
}
```

Which is pretty horrible for complex result sets, and it means I have to go through and give an alias to all the fields whose names clash (person.id and address.id above)

Can the models be split up in Symfony / Doctrine in a way similar to CakePhp?

Or will I have to do that myself before I return the result from the controller?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to have two *"splitted"* result sets in a single query in doctrine, but why would this matter? It doesn't feel right to have two different entity results in a single query.

What are you trying to achieve?

It looks like you're not using the power of doctrine. You seem to have entities, why don't you hydrate them?

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->addSelect('a')
    ->leftJoin('p.address', 'a')
    ->where('p.id', ':id')
    ->setParameter(':id', $id)
;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This will give you an array of `Person` entities linked with `getAddress()` to the `Address` entity which would look like this

```
Object (Acme\FooBundle\Entity\Person) {
    [id] => 596
    [name] => "Michael Bates"
    [foo] => "bar"
    [address] => Object (Acme\FooBundle\Entity\Address) {
        [id] => 125
        [town] => "New York"
        [country] => "USA"
    }
}
```

You'll have all the data you need with this. If you want to serialize it (transform it to json), you may want to use [**jms/serializer**](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer) (or its [**bundle**](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle)) which will handle the hard work.
At controller level, this would look like this

```
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer.serializer');
$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeFoo:Person')->findById($id);

return new Response(
    $serializer->serialize($results, 'json'),
    200,
    [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ]
);
```

Which will generate

```
[
    {
        "id": 596,
        "name": "Michael Bates",
        "address": {
            "id": 125,
            "town": "New York"
        }
    }
]
```

If you need the array of address, you may want to create a new method in the `AddressRepository`

```
public function findByPersonId($id)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->leftJoin('a.person', 'p')
        ->where('p.id', ':id')
        ->setParameter(':id', $id)
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Which will return an array of `Address` matching with `Person` id.
You could combine both to achieve what you were trying at first

```
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();

$persons = $doctrine->getRepository('AcmeFoo:Person')->findById($id);
$addresses = $doctrine->getRepository('AcmeFoo:Address')->findByPersonId($id);

$data = [
    'Person' => $persons,
    'Address' => $addresses
];
```

However, take care of ignoring (in annotation), or removing the join in Person repository if you use this method